# Can I convert any matrix to an image?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have a hypothetical question about image processing:

Supposing we have a grayscale image of size 2x2 which can be represented by an integer matrix (intensity values) with the same dimensions:

```
(050, 150)
(100, 250)
```

After applying some mathematical functions (it can be any mathematical function) the values were changed, for example:

```
(550, 825)
(990, 1120)
```

Is there any way that I can represent this matrix as an image again (considering that the pixels intensity range is 0-255)?

One option which I can think about is to 'normalize' these values by finding the lower value and decreasing it from each value:

```
(0, 275)
(440, 570)
```

Then, finding the higher value and consider it as the 255, for example:

```
(0, 48)
(77, 255)
```

I'm not sure if this approach makes sense (or is efficient to represent the original image).

Anyway, this question is just a conceptual doubt, I'm not trying to implement it, so I haven't any code to show.

Comment: There are millions of ways to do it.  Literally.  But who is to say what the "correct" way to do it is.  What are you actually trying to achieve here?  What is the meaning of these transformations you are performing?

Comment: I don't think exists a 'correct' way, but a better way depending on each case. As I mentioned in the question, I don't have a specific objective here. Actually, I just want to know if it is possible and see some valid example. In this case, you can assume we want to create a new image, based on the matrix, which is similar/approximates the original image.

Answer (score 2):

### Is there any way that I can represent this matrix as an image again
 <sub>( considering that the pixels intensity range is 0-255 )</sub> ?

Oh yes, we can.

The issue is with a colorspace-mapping.

Not just the translation from an unknown range of **`< A, B >`**, but also within a certain and reasonable context of the two different colorspace-ranges, the latter ( the target ) of which is the said `(int) < 0, 255 >` bound.

Given many 2x2 matrices get produced by some unknown process, their colorspace-transcoding ought keep some rationale, that if all were put side by side, the transcoding used should be "non-local" ( having some global anchor for globally equalised normalisation of individual colorspace-transcoding values ) so as not to "devastate" any phenomenon, that was observed in the original colorspace on 4096 x 4096 imagery source, but was "torn" appart, by just locally-normalised `2 x 2` transcoding ( this will lead to incoherrent target colorspaces and the globally observable visual phenomenon will not be visible in a set of target `2x2` sub-views right due to incompatible colorspaces transcoding -- a new kind o non-linear disorder will be introduced due to globally discoordinated colorspace-transcoding and the initial information value of the original will be lost )